# Why my swap function works?

Tags: java, arrays, pass-by-value, primitive-types

As far as I know, Java is passed by value, i.e. when I work with primitive types I can not swap them (if I worked with Objects, however it would be possible). I wrote a program to write down all permutations of an array of integers. To do this I use a `swap` functions that takes as parameters array, two positions, and swap the numbers in these positions. And my program **work**?! Can somebody explain me why? Below is the code:

```
public class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] num) {
        if(num == null || num.length == 0)
            return null;
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();    
        doPermute(num, 0, res);  
        return res;
    }
    public static void doPermute(int[] num, int k, List<List<Integer>> res){
        if(k == num.length){
            res.add(convertArrayToList(num));
            return;
        }
        for(int i = k; i < num.length; i++){
            swap(num, i, k);
            doPermute(num, k+1, res);
            swap(num, k, i);
        }
    }
    public static List<Integer> convertArrayToList(int[] num){
        List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
            res.add(num[i]);
        }
        return res;
    }
    public static void swap(int[] num, int i, int j){
        int temp = num[i];
        num[i] = num[j];
        num[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Look at your swap method. Notice how it doesn't change any of its parameters... there's no `i = ...` or `num = ...` or `j = ...`...

Comment: BTW, swapping object references is as impossible as swapping primitive type values, so your statement "if I worked with Objects, however it would be possible" is incorrect. Don't confuse "modifying an object" with "assigning a new value to a variable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work because you are passing the reference of the Object which you are changing,in your case `int[]`.Note that `int[]` is also an Object.If you just pass the values of array and then try to change it ,it would have been of no use.Consider this

```
//Of little use ,the caller Object is not affected in any way
public static void swap(int i, int j){
      int temp = i
      i = j;
      j = i;
    }  

 swap(num[k], num[i]); //invoking of swap method,caller Object reference is not passed,just assignment of parameter value takes place
```

Since,you have the reference of mutable array Object which you are changing,there is no problem

Answer (score 1):

Java is pass by value. The value of an Object is a reference address. An array (even an `int[]`) is an Object. So,

```
public static void swap(int[] num, int i, int j){
  int temp = num[i];
  num[i] = num[j];
  num[j] = temp;
}
```

the array `num` is modifiable in `swap`. If you look at [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) you will notice the methods take an `Object array`.